# Como mudar a cor dos links da navbar do Bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap-3

Como posso fazer para mudar a cor dos links presentes na navbar padrão do Bootstrap?
Consigo alterar as cores do backgroud da navbar por um arquivo de css externo mas não as cores dos links. Como posso fazer?

Toggle navigation
        
        
        
      
      Brand

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa criar seu estilo css adicional para ser mais especifico no elemento `a`, pois o bootstrap aplica estilos diretamente a tag `a`. 
Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.navbar-nav > li >a{
  color: red;
}
.navbar-nav > li:hover >a,
.navbar-nav > li.active >a
{
  color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Atualizei o exemplo. Verifica se consegue fazer funcionar agora.

Comment: Duas perguntas: 1 - Pq só é possível aplicar a mudança passando o caminho completo do elemento (`.navbar-nav > li:hover >a`) ou por meio de id? Tentei criar uma classe própria para essa mudanças mas não teve efeito.
Existe um 3º efeito de cor que é aplicado quando se clica em um menu dropdown ele aplica uma tonalidade parecida com a cor do `:active` mas não é, `:active` só funciona enquanto o mouse está pressionado, teste o dropdown do [exemplo](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#conte%C3%BAdo-suportado) da doc. Vai ver que ele aplica uma cor enquanto o meno está aberto.